# MongoDB $geoNear distance are huge different from original/google distance

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

This is my url=/location/23.605835/85.277221 //latitude and then longitude

```js
//This is my code to calculate distance

exports.getDistance = async (req, res, next) => {

  const { lat } = req.params;

  const { lng } = req.params;

  const distances = await Seller.aggregate([
     {

      $geoNear: {
        near: {
          type: 'Point',
          coordinates: [lat * 1, lng * 1],
        },
        spherical: true,
        distanceField: 'distance',
        distanceMultiplier: 0.001,
      },
    },
  ]);
  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'success',
    data: {
      data: distances,
    },
  });
};
```

Output

```js
{

    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "data": [
            {
                "_id": "5fc34a0b1ac1e10d1042d8ca",
                "location": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [
                        23.369677,
                        85.321093
                    ]
                },
                "name": "Location One",
                "__v": 0,
                "distance": 5.337871594014329
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The problem here is result distance is totally different from real distance/google distance.
The original distance is about 40km and this giving me 5.3kms.

I don't know what to do please help me out.
Thank You!

Comment: I've been playing around and find the same thing. Although the docs are pretty poor this time.

Comment: I've tested in google maps and calculator sites, in many different ways, all of them even going through (cause it's a short distance) the Earth are around 25.6KM. I'd post your query in the [developer forum](https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/). Maybe google is counting some rugosity in the field, but most maps yield ~26